# O que significa "serialVersionUID"?

Tags: java

O Eclipse sugeriu que eu colocasse este trecho de código:

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

Gostaria de saber qual a finalidade dele... Se alguém puder me explicar, ficarei agradecido.

Comment: Isto irá lhe ajudar: http://blog.caelum.com.br/entendendo-o-serialversionuid/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## O que é

Na prática, esse número seria a versão da sua classe. Você deveria mudá-lo sempre que adicionar, modificar ou remover um atributo da classe.

## Serialização

Isso é usado durante o processo de serialização e desserialização de um objeto/instância daquela classe.

Basicamente, a serialização é o processo onde o Java pega o valor de cada atributo e gera uma sequência de bytes. Junto com essa sequência de bytes, vai o `serialVersionUID`.

Já a desserialização é o inverso, ou seja, o Java pega uma sequência de bytes e coloca nos atributos de um novo objeto. Antes de fazer isso, ele verifica se o `serialVersionUID` salvo é igual ao do objeto sendo criado.

Em tese, isso permite você salvar uma "fotografia" de um objeto, por exemplo, num arquivo em disco e depois restaurar o objeto com os mesmos valores posteriormente.

## A classe mudou, e agora?

Mas, digamos que você salve um objeto num arquivo, modifique seu  programa modificando o tipo de um atributo, execute o programa novamente e tente ler o arquivo para o objeto.

Algo muito estranho pode ocorrer, afinal o Java não tem como saber que sua classe foi modificada desde que você salvou o arquivo, *a menos que o `serialVersionUID` seja diferente*.

Nesse caso, o comportamento esperado é que a exceção `InvalidClassException` seja lançada, o que facilita descobrir o problema, mas não resolve a situação.

Se precisar fazer operações customizadas durante a serialização ou desserialização, o Java permite que você implemente, respectivamente, os métodos `writeObject` e `readObject` onde terá total controle sobre o processo. Veja mais detalhes na [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

## Por que o Eclipse emite um aviso

Para um objeto ser serializado ele precisa ser marcado com a interface `java.io.Serializable`.

Se o Eclipse (ou alguma outra ferramenta que analisa o código) encontra uma classe que implementa `Serializable` direta ou indiretamente, ele entende que é uma boa prática especificar um `serialVersionUID`.

Isso pode ocorrer se a classe:

- implementa `Serializable`;
- implementa uma interface que estende `Serializable`; ou
- estende uma classe que implementa `Serializable`

## O que acontece se eu ignorar?

Caso você não especifique um `serialVersionUID`, mas faça com que a classe implementa `Serializable`, o Java vai usar um mecanismo automático para gerar um `serialVersionUID` durante a compilação da classe.

O valor gerado é baseado nas características da classe conforme a especificação de serialização da linguagem Java. Entretanto, se você usa os mecanismos de serialização, é recomendável especificar o `serialVersionUID`, pois a implementação automática do Java pode variar de alguma forma entre as diferentes versões ou mesmo distribuições.

## Por que usar serialização?

O cenário mais comum de uso da serialização ocorre durante a comunicação entre diferentes processos do Java, por exemplo durante chamadas remotas (RPC) ou em aplicações web distribuídas que compartilham objetos em sessão, onde por vezes ocorre que a sessão de um usuário seja migrada de um servidor para outro, caso as requisições daquele usuário sejam atendidas por servidores diferentes em momentos diferentes.

Problemas podem surgir apenas se os servidores estão executando diferentes versões do mesmo programa, então quando objetos são transmitidos o servidor de destino não consegue "desempacotar" as classes recebidas do servidor de origem.

Devido a todos esses problemas, é mais recomendável evitar usar serialização, seja para salvar objetos em disco, chamadas remotas ou mesmo migrações de sessão.

Nos casos acima, salvar os objetos num formato mais flexível e independente, tal como JSON ou XML, evitará os problemas com a serialização. No caso de chamadas remotas, prefira uma API REST. E para evitar migração de sessão em clusters, não dependa de objetos em sessão, mas use serviços stateless (sem estado) sempre que possível.

Answer (score 3):

> O **serialVersionUID** é um identificador de versão universal para uma classe [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). Na deserialização, esse número é utilizado para garantir que uma classe carregada corresponde exatamente a um objeto serializado. Se nenhuma correspondência do objeto for encontrada, então é lançada uma **InvalidClassException**.

**Obs.:** Traduzido e adaptado de: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=45